# links Slick jS library using wp_enqueue_scripts not pulling

Tags: php

I added the following to my fuctions.php in my active child(wp 2022) theme in wordpress to eneque files from js slick slider library. However I'm getting the 'fail to load resource' error message on my site console

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_register_style('slick-css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/src/library/css/slick.css');
wp_register_style('slick-theme-css', get_template_directory_uri() .'/assets/src/library/css/slick-theme.css');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min-js', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/src/library/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js', array(), '1.11.0');      
wp_enqueue_script('slick-min-js'), get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/src/library/js/slick.min.js');

// Enqueue all CSS & JS files
wp_enqueue_style('slick-css');
wp_enqueue_style('slick-theme-css');
wp_enqueue_script('jquery-min-js');
wp_enqueue_script('slick-min-js');
wp_enqueue_script('myscript-js');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in the console should also show the URL that it's attempting to load. If you look at that you should see that it's attempting to load from the parent theme, but you're presumably trying to load it from the child theme.

The issue is that you're using `get_template_directory_uri()`, which gets the URL to the parent theme. To get the URL to the child theme you need to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`.

That being said, the better functions to use these days are actually `get_parent_theme_file_uri()` and `get_theme_file_uri()`. The latter is what you want to use in this case:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'slick-css', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/src/library/css/slick.css' ) );
    wp_register_style( 'slick-theme-css', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/src/library/css/slick-theme.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-min-js', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/src/library/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js' ), array(), '1.11.0' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-min-js', get_theme_file_uri( 'assets/src/library/js/slick.min.js' ) );

    // Enqueue all CSS & JS files
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'slick-theme-css' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-min-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'slick-min-js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'myscript-js' );
}
```